Does a Moore Machine always require an output for start state?
My lecture notes show all moore machines as having an output even for q0, the starting state.
This video shows a Moore machine without an output for its starting state.
I understand that all Moore machines specify their output by their state, so every time you leave a state, you produce a new output.
I understand that an output is not produced upon entering the initial state.
I want to know if the video I have linked is wrong, or there is some nuance not discussed in my class.

Both model are equivalent. The output at any state is only useful when you transition into that state. In the case of the start state (if you are not visiting it later), you start from that state; thus, you never transition into it. So in that case, it does not matter whether the start state has any output or not. But for the sake of consistency, it should.

to codeR:
For example, for counting the occurrences of a's in a string, it would make sense to have an output of 0 for the start state. But if I have a Moore machine that should produce 110 for an input bab, then does a starting state output affect the output?
